# How does this image countdown work?

Tags: javascript, php

How is this effect achieved?

https://www.onnit.com/emails/_modules/timer/?end=2014-07-07+13:00:00&dark=1

I'm most curious not how the original image is generated but rather how it continues to loop through the time second by second even after a few minutes. There doesn't seem to be any ajax or data being sent

Comment: It appears to just be an animated GIF.   When I download the image and view it locally, it works the same way (without the website attached).

Comment: Also, given the link your provided... you can see that the minutes never changes.   The seconds just keep cycling through.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dynamically generated animated GIF with 60 frames displayed at 1 second intervals. It will loop back to the beginning after 1 minute. You can split it with a tool like this to see...

http://ezgif.com/split/d95a846079.gif